# undefined method `page' for #<Mongoid::

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

When i am trying to click any tab/resource inside rails active admin panel it throw an error:

```
undefined method `page' for #<Mongoid::Criteria:0x007f6e74337680>.
```

I am using rails version : 4.2.7.1 with mongo version '5.0.0'

[image]

Comment: Is it rails 3 or rails 4?

Comment: long long time ago I got similar problem using `activeadmin-mongoid`, maybe [this conversation can help you](https://github.com/elia/activeadmin-mongoid/issues/52). At least at that time it worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

Simply install kaminari-mongoid.

```
gem 'kaminari-mongoid'
```

Comment: I installed the 'kaminari-mongoid' gem and still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you're calling the method `page` on an object that doesn't respond to it.

If you're using sublime text use ctrl + shift + F, then type in '.page'. There will be an entry for where you've misused the method.

Without seeing the actual code / where you're calling the method there isn't a lot else that can be said.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Mongoid fork of ActiveAdmin? Here: https://github.com/elia/activeadmin-mongoid

The error you're getting sounds like a Kaminari paging problem, which this should resolve.